# deadlock caused by two urgent locations

Tags: uppaal

[a small example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juqj9.png)During the simulation, I find that if one state is in urgent location, the other state is about to reach urgent location, and it will deadlock. And I want to verify the upper and lower bounds of time, so I must set urgent location if there is not time. How can I solve this situation?

Comment: Please post a concrete example (eg paste a screenshot). Note that urgent location works just like an invariant: it restricts time globally, and *all* processes become urgent if one process is stuck in urgent location.

Comment: I have added a small example in my question.  In my example, “gtr” is global clock and “t” is local clock. Here, P1 is in the urgent location, and P3 is about to enter the urgent location. I want to check the time of some states, I have to set the state without time to urgent. What is the cause of this situation and how can I solve it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
The deadlock involves the following chain of dependencies:

1. P1 is in urgent location and thus blocking the time passage.
2. P1 is blocked from leaving this urgent location by waiting for `c?` synchronization.
3. P2 is blocked by the guard `t>=3` (and cannot supply `c!` to #2) because `P2.t==0`, moreover clock `P2.t` cannot progress because the time is stopped by #1.
4. P3 is blocked by the guard `t>=2`, where `P3.t in [0,1]`, moreover `P3.t` cannot progress because #1 is blocking.

The deadlock is due to a 1-3 dependency cycle -- you have to break one of these dependencies in order to resolve the deadlock.